# Min Share and Weight which has greater priority in case of getting resources

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn, scheduler

Let say we have 2 queues in fairscheduler.xml. First one with minShare 150 and weight 1 and the second one with minShare 1 and weight 10. Now let say we have 200 cores and equivalent memory. Which one will get more resources?

In the spark documentation I found the following

> The fair scheduler always attempts to meet all active pools’ minimum shares before redistributing extra resources according to the weights. The minShare property can, therefore, be another way to ensure that a pool can always get up to a certain number of resources (e.g. 10 cores) quickly without giving it a high priority for the rest of the cluster.

Does that mean that the first queue will get 150 cores and the second one will get 50?